# are electrolytic capacitors bilateral or unilateral element?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Capacitor is a bilateral element (provides same impedance if direction of current is reversed)- what I studied in Classification of elements.

I was wondering about electrolytic capacitor. If it is a bilateral element then it should provide the same impedance when current is reversed. But polarity is important for electrolytic caps(how they are connected in circuit, -ve terminal usually goes to ground).

So, is it  bilateral or unilateral? and if someone can give more details about the same.

Answer (score 8):

The current through an electrolytic capacitor can flow in both directions, in that sense it is no different from a non-polarized capacitor.

The main difference is that the voltage across an electrolytic capacitor must not be reversed. That is, the voltage between the + terminal and the - has to be larger than or equal to zero volts at all times. Though, a small reverse voltage can sometimes be tolerated.

Comment: "the voltage between the + terminal and the - has to be larger than or equal to zero volts at all times" - this implies +ve terminal is at higher potential than -ve. (And current always flow frm higher potential to lower potential, this Is what I know) then how come direction of current is reversed. will it provide the same impedance when direction of current is reversed? according to definition of bilateral elements.

Comment: Think for another minute: if current was unidirectional you could only charge capacitors. Current can flow from the + to ground while the capacitor remains correctly polarised. Rectified power smoothing capacitors, for example, works in this fashion. The impedance will be mainly the ESR of the capacitor.

Comment: Example: A capacitor is charged to 1V then resistor is connected across the terminals, now the current flows out of the capacitor while the voltage approaches zero volts, but never gets negative.

Comment: @Mario Thank you for the explanation. got your point.

Comment: rule of thumb.. never exceed 10% of Vrating of polar caps in reverse direction to avoid self heating and failure